# How to show and hide mat spinner on API call

Tags: angular, subscribe, angular-material-5

I was trying to show mat spinner on API method call. Below is my API call code on which I subscribe to get the data, Usually it is just 2 min work but this time didn't work, also I know this happens due to a subscribe method so any easy way to implement that?

```
 this.loading = true;

 this.ticketModelService.farmerList
  .subscribe(value => {
    if (value) {
      this.farmerList = value.data;
      this.paginationNumbers = value.recordsFiltered
    }
  })

  this.loading = false;
```

EDIT:
Empty screen for 2 ms.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is your spinner appears and suddenly disappears. So here your loading variable will not wait for API to process and it will disappear within ms. So you should hide your loader in your API callback. So until you're API is processing, loader will stay there. And after getting response you can hide you're loader even if it's an error.

```
 this.loading = true;

 this.ticketModelService.farmerList
  .subscribe(value => {
     this.loading = false;
    if (value) {
      this.farmerList = value.data;
      this.paginationNumbers = value.recordsFiltered
    }
  })
```

Update your code as above.

Comment: this answer should be correct... show us the template as well.
It should be `<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>`

Comment: <mat-progress-bar mode="buffer" *ngIf="loading"></mat-progress-bar> this is my template code. I also know that it's working but the loading progress bar just displays and disappears from the screen but for the milliseconds it is showing an empty screen, which I don't want!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not waiting for your subscription to happen. JavaScript/ Typescript is a synchronous language by default. So it doesn't wait for API call to complete before executing the next line i.e. `this.loading = false;`

So, the solution is to hide the spinner when the API call is complete. To do that we have to write the `this.loading = false;` inside the callback function of the subscribe.

For example, in the html file,

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
```

And in the typescript part,

```
 this.loading = true;

 this.ticketModelService.farmerList.subscribe({
    next: (value) => {
    if (value) {
      this.farmerList = value.data;
      this.paginationNumbers = value.recordsFiltered
    }
  },
  complete: () => {
     this.loading = false;
  }
})
```